# AWK: Skip to next file

Tags: linux, mawk

I have many data files to process but it isn’t necessary to process every record in every file.Is there a way to instruct `awk` to stop precessing the current file and skip to the next file?

Comment: What version of mawk are you using? The version of  [mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/) maintained by Thomas Dickey had nextfile added to it on 20120627.

Comment: @joast - The version of `mawk` that I am using is `1.3.3`, it's the newest version on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that if you are stuck with a version of mawk that is almost 20 years old, then the only option is to process every record in every file unless you install a newer version of mawk, or install gawk, or install any of the other more recent versions of awk.

Comment: @joast sometimes I kinda need that type of beratement to get me to install a new tool.  `gawk` seems pretty worth it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use nextfile statement, it's supported in many awks (except perhaps Solaris)

```
$ awk '/4/{nextfile} 1' <(seq 10) <(seq 10)
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm using `mawk`, it does not support `nextfile` statement.